# Products not visible on Frontend after Import via AvS_FastSimpleImport (based on Magento_ImportExport):

Tags: debugging, avs-fastsimpleimport, ee-1.13.0.1, importexport

I import products via `AvS_FastSimpleImport` (an import module based on Mage_ImportExport) into a store view. They look fine in the backend but are not visible in the specific frontend categories.

When I just open a single product and hit save in the backend, the appear.

Cleaning caches / rebuilding all indices (as far as possible in EE 1.13) does not help.

Is this a known issue? How can I debug this?

I am on Magento EE 1.13.0.1 and wondering if this might be a problem with the new indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround: Rebuild indexes. This is not possible any more in EE 1.13 via backend, but

`n98-magerun.phar index:reindex:all` or via `shell/indexer.php`

still works.

EDIT: This was the answer we got from the enterprise support (using `indexer.php`)

Comment: Any idea why it is not working despite reindexing all products?

Comment: EE 1.13.0.1 or 0.2 ? We not yet did imports on 1.13.0.2

Comment: @therouv but you cleaned the caches? Maybe contact also EE support.